# Accessing Nested Tag Item with getElementsByTagName

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

If the same tag name is used in multiple places within an xml file with the nesting providing unqiueness, what is the best way to specify the particular node of interest.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
dom = parse("inputs.xml")
data_node = dom.getElementsByTagName("outer_level_x")[0].getElementsByTagName('inner_level_y')[0].getElementsByTagName('Data')
```

So, is there a better way to specify the "Data" node nested under "`<outer_level_x><inner_level_y>`"? The specific nesting is always known and a function which recurses calling getElementsByTagName could be written; but, I suspect that I am missing something basic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml.etree.ElementTree provides support for XPath syntax when calling find/findall. Thus, allowing precision when specifying desired tags/attributes.